# Why does laptop's mute button keep blinking and ticking if I open certain websites in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, mute

This is a very strange problem! I am using HP dv6000 laptop with Ubuntu 12.04. Since last few days if I open certain websites in Chrome (e.g. Gmail, Youtube, etc.) the mute button led keeps blinking with "tick tick" sound.

I am using Chrome Version 20.0.1132.47

UPDATE:

I noticed if I disable the flash plugin in Chrome and then open those sites the problem does not appear.

UPDATE 2:

Also, if battery left is less than 80% AND it is not connected to power AND some certain websites are open the problem appears.

Any idea I could get rid of this annoying problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It blinks every time any sound is playing, so when you visit a website that plays sounds it blinks.. (obviously the flash sites are those with more sounds interactions).
It's not a problem but a simply function that will advert you when you are in "mute-mode" and a sound is playing in the background.

I hope it will help!

Comment: +1. Partially correct. It is an alerting system. I at least noticed when I am running low on battery. Connecting the power cable got rid of this blinking.

Comment: edited question with more detail. see update 2.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this might be the solution:

[Lenovo Z560 volume mute/unmute button always blinks while on battery. How do I stop that?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162774/lenovo-z560-volume-mute-unmute-button-always-blinks-while-on-battery-how-do-i-s)

Take a look at the answer posted there (I noticed you commented that you were having the same problem, and I note that this question specifically mentions Chrome and flash)

Short answer:  it might have to do with the Pepper-based Flash built into Chrome.  Try disabling the Pepper-based Flash and use only the normal Flash and see if the blinking continues.  I had a similar problem and disabling the Pepper-flash solved my issue.  (Note that my mute light still goes to solid "on" when sound is playing, but then it goes to solid "off" when the sound stops.  It doesn't blink anymore.

For a longer answer, check the thread posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was fixed by pressing the mute button for 10 to 15 seconds while the power was cut down.

Reason: I think it might have been a static problem with button mechanics.